# Происхождение выражения "и был таков"

Tags: фразеология

Этот вопрос был задан на другом сайте, и я собралась на него ответить. Для начала поискала ответ в Интернете, но, как ни странно, ничего подходящего не нашла.

Значение фразеологического оборота известно — ***быстро исчез, скрылся***, это знают все, но о происхождении сведений не нашлось. Вот, к примеру, целая статья о самом выражении, но и в ней ничего на  эту тему  нет. http://www.winstein.org/publ/8-1-0-196

**А как бы вы ответили на этот вопрос?**

Answer (score 3):

Почему-то никто не отвечает на вопрос, поэтому попробую ответить сама.

Мы часто используем такие выражения, как ***история такова, ситуация такова***, но сразу после этого раскрываем содержание местоименного слова.

А вот фразеологический оборот ***и был таков*** местоимением заканчивается. **И что это значит?**

Ответить на этот вопрос мне помог Интернет, а именно **список синонимов для выражения "и был таков".** Самым интересным вариантом мне показался оборот "поминай как звали" (также менее известное выражение "Митькой звали").

Вспомним басню Крылова:  *И на приветливы Лисицыны слова Ворона каркнула во все воронье горло: Сыр выпал – с ним **была плутовка такова.***

**А какова же она была?**   Этого уже и не вспомнишь, так быстро  исчезла. И как звали, тоже не сразу сообразишь. Короче говоря, ***поминай как звали***, да и только.

И ответ:

**И был таков, что и не вспомнишь каков – так быстро пропал.**

Из журнала "Русский язык" (Сокращение оборота *Поминай, что был таков*, деривата от *Поминай, как звали*).

[https://books.google.ru/books?id=2ipgAAAAMAAJ&q=Сокращение+оборота+Поминай,+что+был+таков&dq=Сокращение+оборота+Поминай,+что+был+таков&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN9sWXx9PfAhUG_ywKHfC4DuEQ6AEIKDAA](https://books.google.ru/books?id=2ipgAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9,+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&dq=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9,+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN9sWXx9PfAhUG_ywKHfC4DuEQ6AEIKDAA)

Comment: Нашёл подтверждение Вашей версии с небольшим уточнением в одном из журналов "Русский язык в школе": "Был таков ... — Сокращение оборота Поминай, что был таков, деривата от Поминай, как звали."

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы просто волшебник, наверное, пользуетесь особыми разыскными методами. А ссылки на журнал у Вас случайно нет?

Comment: [Вот такая](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=2ipgAAAAMAAJ&q=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9,+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&dq=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9,+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF-46MotLfAhUih6YKHfjTCUgQ6AEIJzAA) только. Там посмотрите чуть ниже.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь в ответе есть подтвержденный источник, а это важно.